# Load Byte array to pdf in adobe reader component in windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have a pdf file , in admin all the pdf files are converted into byte array stored in database.

```
public void Getfile()
{
    byte[] file;
    string varFilePath = @"D:\PDFConvertion\pdf\100CountryHouses.pdf";
    try 
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(varFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            }
        }
        SqlConnection sqlCon;
        sqlCon = new SqlConnection("server details");               
        sqlCon.Open();
        using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO pdftest Values(@File)", sqlCon))
        {
            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
            sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        sqlCon.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Converted Success - Length " + Convert.ToString(file.Length));
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        throw Ex;
    }   
}
```

Once file has been uploaded user has view the file , i have used adobe reader component to load the pdf file .

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string varPathToNewLocation = @"D:\PDFConvertion\converted\test.pdf";
            try
            {
                SqlConnection sqlCon;
                sqlCon = new SqlConnection("");
                sqlCon.Open();
                using (var sqlQuery = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT test FROM [dbo].[pdftest] ", sqlCon))
                {

                    using (var sqlQueryResult = sqlQuery.ExecuteReader())
                        if (sqlQueryResult != null)
                        {
                            sqlQueryResult.Read();
                            var blob = new Byte[(sqlQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
                            sqlQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
                            using (var fs = new FileStream(varPathToNewLocation, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                                fs.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                        }
                }
                sqlCon.Close();
                axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(@"D:PDFConvertion\converted\test.pdf");

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                throw Ex;
            }
        }
```

But i want to load the file in adobe reader component directly without storing in location.

Comment: Here's a hint: don't ever use `try/catch (Exception ex){throw ex;}` Just leave off the try/catch block entirely.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like a LoadStream api.  A quick search of the Acrobat SDK didn't seem to turn anything up.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web application you can put the pdf file into the Response object of the web page. Then the browser opens acrobat reader automatically. Here is the c# snippet:

```
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

// if blob is the byte array of the pdf file
Response.BinaryWrite(blob);  
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: No its a not web application .